# How can I measure fricative voicing?

Tags: phonetics, praat

everyone! This questions regards Praat. I'm trying to find a way to measure the voicing property of word-final fricatives in L2 English. Learners (and often native speakers) often produce forms such as [bӕgs] instead of [bӕgz], and there are also gradient productions involved. As you can see in the picture, fricative voicing is almost unexistent. However, if we consider the fact that there's a continuum, how would I be able to measure productions from fully unvoiced to fully voiced?

[image]